# Trouble storing data from Firestore(SwiftUi)

Tags: swiftui

This is Model that I am using inside the DataManager class

```
struct Workout: Identifiable {
    
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var exercises: [testExercise]
}

struct testExercise: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var tests: [Test]
}

struct Test: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var commonName: String
}
```

[image]

I've tried moving the exercise variable but when I do that the array will no longer have any of the exercises. Can anyone help?

Comment: `getDocuments` works asynchronously. The completion handlers are called later in time. You need `DispatchGroup` to control the loop – or use the `async/await` API if available. By the way: Please post **text**, not screenshots.